# Change iframe src attr on click using event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change iframe src on click. Due to some reason I wish to use `event.target` and not any other method.

I am trying to achieve the same using the below code but it is not working.

`html` code:

```
<div id="div2" class="sim-row-edit-video">
<iframe class="frame" width="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
</div>
```

I would rather not use class or id to change the same as there are many with similar class. Kindly use `event.target`.

`js` code:

```
$(".sim-row-edit-video").click(function(){
    alert("video clicked");
    $(event.target).attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/drOnSwo1Ob0');

//event.target.src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png';
});
```

How can I change the src of the clicked iframe?

Comment: You can't detect clicks on a cross-domain iframe document.

Comment: i can detect the click on parent div, any solution using that please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$(this).find('iframe')`. Here `$(this)` is the object of clicked element and `find('iframe')` will find the `iframe` element inside the clicked element. Following snippet is an example based on code you have provided.

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-video").click(function(){
    console.log("video clicked");
    console.log("old src: " + $(this).find('iframe').attr('src'));
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/drOnSwo1Ob0');
    console.log("new src: " + $(this).find('iframe').attr('src'));
//event.target.src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" class="sim-row-edit-video">
<iframe class="frame" width="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
</div>
```