# How to change iframe src when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to change src of an iframe, to change trailers, but after trying to utilize the answer of a different post: [iframe src change on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176484/iframe-src-change-on-button-click) but I still couldn't get it to work, it keeps saying: "newSrc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index)(9:65)"

I want to thank everyone for their comments, I found the problem and solved it, I forgot to link the javascript on the page I was working on, the dumbest mistake that I could've made

Thank you Chris for helping with extra tips
and Nermin for making me realise my dumb mistake

```js
function newSrc() {
  var e = document.getElementById("Menu_trailers");
  var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("trailers").src=newSrc;
}
```

```html
      <figure class="trailer">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sfAc2U20uyg" id="trailers"> </iframe>
      </figure>
      <section class="button_trailer">
        <select id="Menu_trailers">
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sfAc2U20uyg">Trailer 1</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o-L1mMZ31hM">Trailer 2</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="newSrc();" class="button_next_trailer">Change trailer</button>
      </section>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name for a local variable and a function, and you can read the <select>'s .value directly, but other than that, the code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/adzrv10p/ (note that in order to solve this problem, you shouldn't google "how to change iframe src on button click", what you want is a) handle a button click b) change the attribute of an HTMLElement; if you split your problem into its parts and generalize the requirement, you will have a much easier time finding existing solutions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309180/change-iframe-src-attr-on-click-using-event-target

Comment: Are you sure that your function is defined and javascript executed before the HTML is loaded and you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS code to get the src from the select menu, then set it to the iframe element

```
function newSrc() {
  // Get The Select Menu Element
  var e = document.getElementById("Menu_trailers");
  // Set Select Menu Value (Selected Option) To Be The src Of The iframe
  document.getElementById("trailer").src = e.value;
}
```